# How to use an external library with a rosjava

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to modify the example: Talker.java to use an external library saved as .jar

In eclipse, I have updated buildPath, but when I execute roscore, system doesn't run.

I am not sure if I have to add some line in build.xml or the dependencies.xml

In build.xml I added:

```
  <path id="classpath">
    <pathelement path="${ros.compile.classpath}" />
    <pathelement location="/usr/local/lejos/lib/pc/pccomms.jar" />
  </path>
```

But roscore fails too.

How to solve my problem?

Happy new year

Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12492/how-to-use-an-external-library-with-a-rosjava/) by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) on ROS Answers with karma: 274 on 2011-12-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the problem updating manifest.xml

```
  <export>
    <!-- 
    <rosjava-src location="src/main/java" />
     -->
    <rosjava-src location="src" /> 
    <rosjava-pathelement location="target/" groupId="org.ros" artifactId="org.ros.rosjava.tutorial.pubsub" version="0.0.0" built="true" />
    <rosjava-pathelement location="/usr/local/lejos/lib/pc/pccomm.jar" />
 </export>
```

---

Originally posted by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) with karma: 274 on 2011-12-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pickman](https://answers.ros.org/users/24593/pickman/) on 2016-08-04**:
Excuse me what is the "target/" directory in this case?